# Can a C++ Compiler Eliminate a Volatile Local Var that is not Read

Tags: c++, visual-c++, c++11, volatile, intrinsics

Say, I have this code:

```
int f() {
  volatile int c;
  c=34;
  return abc();
}
```

The **volatile int c** is never read.  But it is marked as **volatile**, can the compiler eliminate it altogether?  My testing in Visual C++ 2010 shows contradictory results.  In VC++, if I enable optimization (maximizing speed) the above function contains a local variable called c (by looking at the generated assembly listing).  But, instead of using assignment operator, I also tried to initialize the variable by a compiler intrinsic function like memset() (and enable using compiler intrinsic functions), the variable is eliminated.

```
int f() {
  volatile int c;
  memset((void*)&c,34, 1); 
  return abc();
}
```

So according to the C++ standard, can compiler eliminate the volatile int c? I'm thinking probably there is some inconsistent behaviour in VC++ related to how intrinsic functions optimize volatile variable.

Comment: How do you perform the initialisation with memset? What does the code look like (`memset(&c, 34, 1)` should not compile!).

Comment: memset((void*)&c,34, 1); probably c is considered void *, no longer volatile

Comment: For Finagle's sake *don't use casts as hammers*.

Comment: The "inconsistent" behavior is simply that "if you don't tell the function that it is operating on volatile memory (by casting away volatile-ness), then it won't know that it is operating on volatile memory". Also, undefined behavior and evil casts.

Comment: See my own question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15538366/can-memset-function-call-be-removed-by-compiler - it's `memset` that gets optimized-out. After that is done, there is nothing accessing volatile variable, so compiler is free to remove it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> So according to the C++ standard, can compiler eliminates the volatile int c?

**No**. `volatile`-qualified objects are used for reading from or writing to the hardware, and the side-effects of assigning a `volatile` object are observable.

Therefore, in compliance with the constraints on optimizations placed by the so-called ["as-if" rule](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15718262/what-exactly-is-the-as-if-rule), conforming implementations are not allowed to optimize away `c`. The "*as-if*" rule is formally introduced in Paragraph 1.9/1 of the C++11 Standard:

> The semantic descriptions in this International Standard define a parameterized nondeterministic abstract
>   machine. This International Standard places no requirement on the structure of conforming implementations.
>   In particular, they need not copy or emulate the structure of the abstract machine. Rather, conforming
>   implementations are required to emulate (only) the **observable behavior** of the abstract machine as explained
>   below

And the concept of "*observable behavior*" is defined in paragraph 1.9/8:

> The least requirements on a conforming implementation are:
>
> — **Access to volatile objects are evaluated strictly according to the rules of the abstract machine**.
>
> — At program termination, all data written into files shall be identical to one of the possible results that
>   execution of the program according to the abstract semantics would have produced.
>
> — The input and output dynamics of interactive devices shall take place in such a fashion that prompting
>   output is actually delivered before a program waits for input. What constitutes an interactive device
>   is implementation-defined.
>
> **These collectively are referred to as the *observable behavior* of the program**. [...]

Since access to `volatile` objects must be evaluated strictly according to the rules of the abstract machine, compilers are not allowed to optimize away `c` and the corresponding assignment operation.

Answer (score 7):

`memset((void*)&c,34, 1);` has undefined behaviour (§7.1.6.1/6). The compiler is therefore allowed to produce any result.

> If an attempt is made to refer to an object defined with a volatile-qualified type through the use of a glvalue with a non-volatile-qualified type, the program behavior is undefined.

Please, do not use casts like that, much less C-style casts. When one does not know what the correct C++ cast is for a certain situation, it is likely a situation where one should not be casting anything.